# Lambda expression cannot be used as expected

Tags: vb.net, lambda

The following code produces the compiler error "Expression expected" (Sub is underlined).

```
Dim lambda As Action(Of Integer) = Sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x)
```

Why does this not work?

Note: The corresponding C# code works:

```
Action<int> lambda = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using Visual Studio 2008. Action lambdas in VB.NET (`Sub` keyword) [have been added in VB 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we86c8x2.aspx#multilinelambda), which ships with Visual Studio 2010. The same is true for multi-line lambdas, by the way.

Note that this is not a framework issue, but a compiler issue: You can use action lambdas even in .NET 3.5 projects, as long as you use the VS 2010 compiler.

C# had action lambdas before VB, which is why the C# example works even in VS 2008.

Comment: This explains it all. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar in VB.net 3.5 then?

Comment: @SimonDugré: Sure, it works perfectly fine in VB.net 3.5! You just need to use VS 2010 or above.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck with VS 2008, that's why. Sorry my bad, I have not read correctly your answer.