# Convert c# code with inline delegate to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

I need to convert this code to vb.net

```
public IDisposable WriteLock()
{
    EnterWriteLock();
    return new LockDisposer(delegate() { ExitWriteLock(); });
}
```

This is what I got with the online converters

```vb
Public Function WriteLock() As IDisposable
    EnterWriteLock()
    Return New LockDisposer(Sub() ExitWriteLock()) <-- Error Line
End Function
```

I am using .net 2.0

Comment: You say that you're using .Net 2.0, does that mean you're targeting that or compiling in that? You'll need at least a 3.5 compiler for vb.net lambda expressions.

Comment: I am using v2008 and targeting .net2, the reason being that I have a large solution and upgrading to .net 4 would tame me a lot of time, especially having over 50 reports which also needs to be converter

Comment: *"Action lambdas in VB.NET (`Sub` keyword) have been added in VB 10, which ships with Visual Studio 2010. The same is true for multi-line lambdas, by the way."* according to [this answer by Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8620232/880990) to the SO question [Lamba expression cannot be used as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620208/lamba-expression-cannot-be-used-as-expected).

Comment: At the first look... A `Sub()` does not return values. Your code should looks like: `Public Function WriteLock() As IDisposable
    EnterWriteLock()
    Return New LockDisposer(Function()
                                ExitWriteLock()
                            End Function)
End Function`

Comment: @MaciejLos: `ExitWriteLock()` does not return a value.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, maybe not, but based on that piece of code we can only guess. Because of `Return New LockDisposer()` i'm guessing that it should be a function ;)

Comment: Probably the `LockDisposer` constructor has a parameter of type `Action`. `Sub() ExitWriteLock()` is an input parameter to the constructor of `LockDisposer`. Look at the C# delegate, it calls `ExitWriteLock();` without `return` statement.

Comment: Assumed constructor signature of `LockDisposer` is `Public Sub New(exitLock As Action)`

Comment: Voted for a reopen because AFAIK the "already answered" solution is not supported in .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Smith I didn't use VB.NET until 4.x, but this might work: `Return New LockDisposer(AddressOf ExitWriteLock)`

Comment: The comments and answers are all based on speculation until @Smith shows us the signature of the `LockDisposer` constructor <hint, hint>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Public Function WriteLock() As IDisposable
     EnterWriteLock()
     Return New LockDisposer(AddressOf ExitWriteLock)
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is missing end sub of the delegate:

```vb
Public Function WriteLock() As IDisposable
    Return New LockDisposer(Sub()
                                ExitWriteLock()
                            End Sub) 
End Function
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pRm3ua)

Comment: I tried it, but still does not work? the `Sub`, and `End Sub` is flagged as invalid expressions

Comment: I added a live demo to answer please have a look.

Comment: Thanks, but note, I am using .net 2.0, its in the question

Comment: `End Sub` is only required for muli-line [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: The original C# code was a multi-line lambda (notice the braces), so technically the VB multi-line lambda is the equivalent.

Comment: Yes, but since the OP used a single-lime lambda, a missing `End Sub` was not causing the issue.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas how would the vb multi and single line lambdas *not* be equivalent?

Comment: @djv: A VB expression lambda has no 'End Sub' or 'End Function'.  For a single-line lambda, you have 2 choices in VB: an expression lambda or a "multi-line" lambda with only one line.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas the single and multi line (including `End Sub`) lambdas are equivalent, so technically they would both be equivalent to the original C#